# IAR - Adding pre-build command to delete an object file

Tags: iar, prebuild

In IAR embedded workbench IDE, I need to force the compilation of a file, every time I build the project (in order to recompile `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`).

So I need to "touch" that file (i.e., delete the corresponding object file).

I went into the project options --> C/C++ Compiler --> Extra Options --> Use command line options.

In there, I entered a shell command for deleting that file, but without luck.
I tried several different ways of doing it, including to call a batch file.
Examples:

1. `del "$OBJ_DIR$\mng_version.o"`
2. `cmd /c "del "$OBJ_DIR$\mng_version.o""`
3. `pre_build.bat`

None of these worked.
Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use

```
Project options -> Build Actions
```

and enter a command into the Pre-build command line.  This can be a batch file invocation.  I have a utility that increments a build number declaration in a version file that is then re-compiled on every build.

This is the same on the MSP-430, ARM and Atmel AVR-32 versions of the IAR toolset.

Comment: Thank you. May I just add, that in order to be able to locate the batch file alongside the project (i.e., in the same path), I needed to add '$PROJ_DIR$\' before the batch file name. Also, in order to have the batch file performing an action on a file within my project, I needed to pass '$PROJ_DIR$\' as an argument to the batch file, and to use it as '%1\' inside the batch file.